# Passing variable names from formula into tidy function with rlang

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang, tidyeval

I've been reading through the tidy evaluation book, several questions, and a few other resources and I still can't find a straight answer to this.

Suppose I have a formula object in R, say `x ~ y + z`, and a function `f`, that I define like the following.

f <- function(.data, a_formula) {
.data %>%
select(SOMETHING HERE)
}

I want evaluating `f(df, a_formula)` to give the same result as `df %>% select(x, y, z)` without having to manually specify the formula components.

I know `rlang` has a few functions to deal with formulas, and there is `all.vars()` from base R, but I am not sure what I need to put in the internal `select()` function within `f()` for this to evaluate how I want. Is the best answer to just do basic string manipulations until I get what I want? I would prefer if there was some way for the tidy evaluation stuff to handle this behind the scenes, so, for example, `f(df, formula(x ~ .))` would result in `f %>% select(x, everything())` as usual for `dplyr`.

So basically what I am asking is, is there a way for me to extract the variables from a formula and have `select()` evaluate them as normal?

Comment: why must it be a formula? and if a formula why 2 sided formula??. Try `f <- function(.data, a_formula) { .data %>% select(all.vars( a_formula)) }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've basically already found all the parts you need, you just need to put them together with the `all_of()` helper function. For example

```
library(dplyr)

f <- function(.data, a_formula) { 
  .data %>% select(all_of(all.vars(a_formula))) 
}

# test with built-in iris data frame
f(iris, Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width)
```

If you want to do something special for `.`, then just add that in

```
f <- function(.data, a_formula) { 
   if ("." %in% all.vars(a_formula)) return(.data)
  .data %>% select(all_of(all.vars(a_formula))) 
}
f(iris, Sepal.Length ~ .)
```

Comment: Thank you! I completely forget about the selection helpers while I was doing this.